# Get the path of saved_model.pb after training on ML engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I have been using the python client API of ML engine to create training jobs of some canned estimators. What I'm not able to do is get the path of the saved_model.pb on GCS because the path it is stored in has a timestamp as a dir name. Is there anyway I can get this using a regular expression or something on python client, so that I'll be able to deploy the model with correct path.

The path seems to be in this format right now -

> **gs://bucket_name/outputs/export/serv/`timestamp`/saved_model.pb**

---

UPDATE

Thanks [shahin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9388302/shahin-vnia) for the answer.
So I wrote this, which gives me the exact path that I can pass to the deploy_uri for ml engine.

```
from google.cloud import storage

def getGCSPath(prefix):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    mlist = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)
    for line in mlist:
        if 'saved_model.pb' in line.name:
            return line.name[:-14]

# print getGCSPath('output/export/serv/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import cloudstorage as gcs
bucket = os.environ.get('BUCKET')
page_size = 1
stats = gcs.listbucket(bucket + '/outputs/export/serv', max_keys=page_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gsutil and tail:

```
MODEL_LOCATION=$(gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}/outputs/export/serv | tail -1)
gcloud ml-engine models create ${MODEL_NAME} --regions $REGION
gcloud ml-engine versions create ${MODEL_VERSION} --model ${MODEL_NAME} --origin ${MODEL_LOCATION} --runtime-version $TFVERSION
```

Comment: I was hoping for a python client answer.

Comment: Run the bash script in python
import os
os.system('gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}/outputs/export/serv | tail -1')